# SQL Count / sum in order clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a "Leaderboard" for a tool I am working on and I need to pull some numbers together and get the count of records across multiple rows.

What you will see in this Stored Procedure is me trying to order the records by the sum of 2 columns.

Any tips on how to accomplish this?

```
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
        BEGIN
            SELECT DISTINCT(whoAdded),
                    count(tag) as totalTags,
                    count(DISTINCT data) as totalSubmissions
            FROM   Tags_Accounts
            GROUP BY whoAdded
            ORDER BY SUM(totalTags + totalSubmissions) DESC
            FOR    XML PATH ('leaderboard'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
        END 
END
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Invalid column name 'totalTags'. and totalSubmissions

Comment: Yes, you are getting these errors since the `totalTags` and `totalSubmissions` are only aliases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by putting it in a derived table:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT(whoAdded) AS whoAdded,
        count(tag) as totalTags,
        count(DISTINCT data) as totalSubmissions
    FROM   Tags_Accounts
    GROUP BY whoAdded
    ) a
ORDER BY totalTags + totalSubmissions DESC
FOR    XML PATH ('leaderboard'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root')
```

Alternatively, you can order by the aggregates, but I think the above is a bit cleaner/less redundant:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(whoAdded) as whoAdded,
    count(tag) as totalTags,
    count(DISTINCT data) as totalSubmissions
FROM   Tags_Accounts
GROUP BY whoAdded
ORDER BY SUM(count(tag) + count(DISTINCT data)) DESC
FOR    XML PATH ('leaderboard'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root')
```

Comment: The first one returns
Invalid column name 'totalTags'.
Invalid column name 'totalSubmissions'.

Comment: Does the inner `SELECT` work? If not, what errors do you get there?

Comment: Can you run it without the `ORDER BY`?

Comment: It also throws the error : No column name was specified for column 1 of 'a'.

Comment: Without the order by, it returns the error noted above aboout column 1 of a

Comment: I took out the `DISTINCT` as I didn't think that was needed. Maybe it is. Updating now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41748/discussion-between-sbb-and-jerad-rose)

Answer (score 0):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
        BEGIN
            ;WITH CTE AS(
            SELECT DISTINCT(whoAdded),
                    count(tag) as totalTags,
                    count(DISTINCT data) as totalSubmissions
            FROM   Tags_Accounts
            GROUP BY whoAdded)
            SELECT * FROM CTE
            ORDER BY SUM(totalTags + totalSubmissions) DESC
            FOR    XML PATH ('leaderboard'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
        END 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `SUM()`, simply use `+` to add the values, and just use the expressions rather than the column aliases:

```
ORDER BY count(*) + count(DISTINCT data) DESC
```